# Spring boot API request limit issue

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, tomcat9, docker-container

I have developed a microservice using Spring Boot and deployed it as a docker container and when doing performance testing the service I see that the maximum number of threads that created to the service is 20 at any point in time even though the number of calls made is much higher. I have even set the max thread to 4000 and also set Max connection to 10000 along with all db configuration and server has 24 core and 64 gb ram still no improvement Are there any limitations with respect to number of calls that can be made to a microservice developed using Spring Boot or is the issue is with docker container? Or is this normal?

Comment: In theory no. In practice it depends on memory, db connections, pool sizing, processor architecture, ... and many things more.

Comment: Yes but I thought when we increase ram and core we get better throughout but in my case I am unable find the bottleneck as I have executed all possible configuration and still Getting only 50tps in all possible configuration

Comment: Depending on your Java and Docker version, that ram or cores might not get detected by your JVM. So even if you have multiple cores it might even be they aren't even (fully) utilized due to this. The problem with these kind of things is they are actually very hard to determine in a question on StackOverflow as there are so many moving parts that influence one another.